# Add fields from User to a customModel, in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

In django-admin, I try to add specifics fields from **User** django class, in two custom models **Practitionner** and **Patient**.

Visually, on the django admin interface, when i click on Patient, i need to have User + Patient fields, and the same for Practitionner. Instead of creating two user + one patient + one practionner and make manually the relationships.

Here are the two models code :

```
class Practitioner(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, verbose_name="Numéro de téléphone professionel")
    office = models.ForeignKey(locals.Office)
    exams = models.ManyToManyField(exams.Exam)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.first_name + " " + self.user.last_name

class Patient(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, verbose_name="Numéro de téléphone fixe")
    mobile_phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, verbose_name="Numéro de téléphone portable")
    birth_date = models.DateField(verbose_name="Date de naissance")
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="Ville")
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="Pays")
    streetNumber = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(verbose_name="N°")
    streetName = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="Nom")
    postalCode = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name="Code postal")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.first_name + " " + self.user.last_name
```

The code below represents the idea, I used the *inline* system but it is not valid because the User has no foreign key to Practitionner :

```
class UserInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = User

class PractitionerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [UserInline]

admin.site.register(Practitioner, PractitionerAdmin)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please give more detail about the issue with 'doing the reverse'? It would be good to see your model definitions for `Patient` and `Practitioner`. You say it's "because I have an other model Patient, that use User model too, and they need to be at two distinct places." 1. It sounds like maybe there should be a foreignkey from `Patient` to `Practitioner`. 2. Is this something that could be solved by using the `related_name` attribute so that the reverse accessors don't clash?

Comment: Why are you trying to use an inline on a OneToOne Field? That does not make sense to me! If you want to add fields of the User model to your Practioner model why not make it inherit from User: class Practionser(User): - then the fields will show up in the admin.

Comment: @ger.s.brett I followed the documentation : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model, so i've stole the same ideas.
I tried to inherit Practionner from User class, but by this way it will not  continue to use the User table in the database.

Comment: @nimasmi yes sorry, I've updated the question post with the infos you have asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by bringing the inline into the User admin:

```
class PractitionerInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Practitioner

class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines=[PractitionerInline]

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Note the unregistering of User, as this has been registered by auth before.

If you want to do the same thing with the patient you need to "copy" the user model and register this:

```
class PatientUser(User):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

class PatientInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Patient

class PatientUserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines=[PatientInline]

admin.site.register(PatientUser, PatientUserAdmin)
```

Note that you should also define the queryset method for both Admin classes and filter the Users that are Patients or Practitioners accordingly.

Edit - this is how to do the latter:

```
class PatientUserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines=[PatientInline]
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(PatientUserAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        qs = qs.exclude(patient__isnull=True)
        return qs
```

Comment: Ok thanks you, I used your second code for Patient and Practitionner. It is nice, but as you said, the problem is that the same users are listed in both models. I've seen that i can use list_filter = ( ('user', admin.RelatedOnlyFieldListFilter),), but it won't works because i can only access User's fields within classes that inherit from ModelAdmin. 
How it can be remedied. ?

Comment: Ah nice, i see better now, I completely forgot the reverse relation. Thanks you again, the problem is solved